# installing Rstudio on hortonworks HDP docker image

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

I am trying to install the RStudio on Hortonworks HDP 2.6 docker image. I am following the steps mentioned here. 
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/25558/running-sparkr-in-rstudio-using-hdp-24.html

The problem is after the following steps.

```
sudo yum install --nogpgcheck rstudio-server-rhel-0.99.893-x86_64.rpm
```

I am getting below error

```
Marking rstudio-server-rhel-0.99.893-x86_64.rpm to be installed
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

  * base: centos2.hti.pl  * epel: mirror.nsc.liu.se  * extras:
 centos2.hti.pl  * updates: ftp.vectranet.pl
 http://dev2.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com/repo/dev/master/utils/repodata/repomd.xml:
 [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403
 Forbidden" Trying other mirror. To address this issue please refer to
 the below knowledge base article

 https://access.redhat.com/solutions/69319

 If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a
 ticket with Red Hat Support.

 Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for
 repository: sandbox. Please verify its path and try again
```

The link the error is of no help. Could someone please let me know what is happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286326/cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomd-xml-for-repository-sandbox-please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286326/cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomd-xml-for-repository-sandbox-please Try this, i am doing it, it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d

 mv sandbox.repo /tmp
```

Then the `yum install --nogpgcheck rstudio-server-rhel-0.99.893-x86_64.rpm`.
Its worked, now moved sandbox.repo from /tmp to its original palace.