# Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: sandbox. Please verify its path and try again

Tags: python, hadoop, pip, hortonworks-data-platform

I have HDP 2.6.1 installed on VirtualBox and am attempting to run

`yum install python-pip`

However, the error below appears:

```
http://dev2.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com/repo/dev/master/utils/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/69319

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: sandbox. Please verify its path and try again
```

As I need pip to install MRJob, how can I sucessfuly install pip?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I fixed this by:

`cd /etc/yum.repos.d
 mv sandbox.repo /tmp`

If you look in that file you see it refers to the http://dev2.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com as baseurl.

Then the `yum install python-pip` worked but just in case I need that sandbox repo again I moved it back `mv /tmp/sandbox.repo .`

EDIT - I am on the docker image but I guess would be the same for the VM.
A

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

You can set the enabled flag as 0 inside sandbox.repo. You will need to perform the operation as root.

```
# su root 
# vi /etc/yum.repos.d/sandbox.repo
```

Go to INSERT mode and modify the line enabled=1 to enabled=0. Save and Exit.
Finally, run a yum clean and try the installations again.

```
# yum clean all
```